# LibGDX Box2D Drawing issue

Tags: libgdx

I have a problem with drawing bodys from Box2D on the Screen.

You can see that the Box2DDebugRenderer draws all the old positions on the Screen, how can i avoid that?

[Running application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9LxF.png)

ignore all the lines in render() except for the last one.

```
public class GameRenderer {

SpriteBatch batcher;
private GameWorld myWorld;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;
public Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();

public GameRenderer(GameWorld myWorld){
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true, 320.0f, 200.0f);
    batcher = new SpriteBatch();
    batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    this.myWorld = myWorld;

}

public void render(){
    batcher.begin();
    bodies = myWorld.getBodies();
    if(bodies != null){
        //Entity e = (Entity) bodies.get(0).getUserData();
        //batcher.draw(e.getImage(), bodies.get(0).getPosition().x, bodies.get(0).getPosition().y, 10, 10);
    }
    batcher.end();
    renderer.render(myWorld.world, cam.combined);
}
```

}

Comment: i have edited my original post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibGDX - The window is not being cleaned every frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214351/libgdx-the-window-is-not-being-cleaned-every-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the desired clear color and then call glClear() with the desired buffers to clear. You are then free to render a fresh frame with new scene graphics.

```
@Override
public void render() {

  Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 1, 0, 0, 1 );
  Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

  // scene render code...
}
```